# Kafka Connect plugin classpath

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

As described in Kafka confluent:

> As described in Installing Connect Plugins, connector plugin JAR files are placed in the plugin path (Connect worker property: plugin.path). However, a few connectors may require that you additionally export the CLASSPATH to the plugin JAR files when starting the connector (`export CLASSPATH=<path-to-jar-files>`). While not recommended, **CLASSPATH** is required for these connectors because Kafka Connect uses classloading isolation to distinguish between system classes and regular classes, and some plugins load system classes (for example, `javax.naming` and others in the package **javax**). An example error message showing this issue is provided below. If you see an error that resembles the example below, in addition to adding the plugin path, you must also `export CLASSPATH=<path-to-jar-files>` when starting the connector.

One thing I don't understand is that when the plug-in class loader that operates as child first tries to load a system class and cannot find a class, it delegates to the parent class loader, which is the system class loader, so that the system class can be loaded. I don't know why classpath has to be specified.